# I'm restoring a database and I need to lock any activity to it from my Java application while doing it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using a c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource with Spring and Hibernate and the solution I came up with is a custom Datasource class that accepts the actual Datasource in it's constructor. I delegate all the responsibility to the actual datasource. I have a locked boolean which when set to true makes getConnection() wait until locked is false again.

I was just wondering whether anyone can see flaws in my approach or have better alternatives? Thanks!

```
public interface LockableDataSource extends DataSource {
    public boolean isLocked();

    public void setLocked(boolean locked);
}


public class LockableDataSourceImpl implements LockableDataSource{

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private boolean locked = false;


    public LockableDataSourceImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        while(locked){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    public Connection getConnection(String s, String s1) throws SQLException {
        while(locked){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection(s, s1);
    }

    public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getLogWriter();
    }

    public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter printWriter) throws SQLException {
        dataSource.setLogWriter(printWriter);
    }

    public void setLoginTimeout(int i) throws SQLException {
        dataSource.setLoginTimeout(i);
    }

    public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getLoginTimeout();
    }

    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> tClass) throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.unwrap(tClass);
    }

    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> aClass) throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.isWrapperFor(aClass);
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    synchronized public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several flaws:

1. You don't synchronize access to your flag variable, so you have no guarantees re other threads seeing its state.
2. You return `null` on `InterruptedException`, which will cause hard-to-diagnose exceptions in the calling code.
3. You're re-implementing synchronization primitives that already exist.

By far the best solution is to just shut down your app when mucking with the database.

If you really want to leave your application hung while the database is down, look at [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the restore is done from the application itself(VM Appliance) so shutting down the Application isn't really an option unless I develop another Maintenance type application that runs alongside

Comment: I have now updated my answer with the setLocked method synchronized  as well as printing the stack trace if the threads are interrupted...

Answer (score 1):

I would have two concerns.

1. The current code is not thread-safe.
2. Most non-trivial systems requires using more than one application instances. Your lock will not prevent other instances from acting on the DB.

Comment: I've synchronized the setLocked method now... The application is a VM appliance and not an N-Tier system. So there is 1 application for 1 database.

Comment: @Brian: You must synchronize for all method that accesses the field you are guarding. I.e. you have to also synchronize on the isLocked method. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to touch up on Multithreaded programming!